# Как передать в Maven строку в качестве параметра в bash-скрипте?

Tags: bash

Есть bash-скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash

mvn (...) -DsomeParam=$1
```

Мне надо передать в него в качестве параметра строку, содержащую пробелы. Если я сделаю это как есть, то Maven воспримет то что после пробела как следующий параметр.

Надо написать что-то типа  **mvn (...) -DsomeParam='"' + $1 + "'"**, но не знаю как.

Comment: Может так?    

    #!/bin/bash
    mvn (...) -DsomeParam="$1"

Comment: Спасибо работает!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
mvn (...) "-DsomeParam=$1"
```

Comment: Ого, и так работает.